# How do I make the Drupal default From: e-mail different than the email of the user who receives system e-mails?

Tags: email, drupal

I am creating a site that requires admin approval before creating a user account. In *Site Information* settings I have set the site's e-mail address to "noreply@mysite.com"

New registrants request an account and they correctly get an e-mail From:noreply@mysite.com
No problems there.

However, the useful "Approve New User" e-mail also gets sent to "noreply@mysite.com" when I need it to go to "me@mysite.com." The noreply address is strictly a garbage address I will never check.

So, how do I set up a different email for the default "From:" address and the default system alert e-mail recipient address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a module, User Registration Notification, that does what I needed. Keep the site e-mail "no-reply" and change the To: value in the module to "me".

[User registration notification](http://drupal.org/project/user_register_notify)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Drupal's hook_mail_alter to intercept the email that gets sent to noreply@mysite.com send it to the desired email address. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_mail_alter/6

It's also possible to do this kind of customization using Triggers and Actions:

http://drupal.org/node/199254

http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/trigger